# ¿Como muestro todos los valores de un archivo WAV en forma de un array de NumPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, wav

Poseo un archivo WAV de 5 segundos donde la frecuencia es puramente 440hz, y quiero conocer los valores enteros que contiene el archivo, en modo texto; asi que desarrolle el siguiente script:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile

rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('440Hz.wav')
file = open('440Hz.txt','w+')
file.write(str(data))
file.close
print('Listo :)')
```

La salida en el archivo "440Hz.txt" es la siguiente:

```
[    0  1421  2835 ... -4238 -2836 -1420]
```

El problema radica en que deseo saber absolutamente todos los valores, sin los puntos sucesivos, pero no logro hallar una solución. Talvez deba cambiar de libreria, o tenga que agregar un parametro más y desconozco de él.

Espero que puedan resolver mi duda ya que por mas que busqué no encontré una solución, o talvez no se como encontrarla.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy (`data` es un array de NumPy) por defecto formatea el retorno de `__str__` truncando el array para mostrar solo una representación resumida del mismo con el fin de evitar problemas de legibilidad, de buffer y de rendimiento al imprimir arrays muy extensos (lo cual es común, tu propio array debe estar en torno a los 50000 elementos...).

Puedes modificar esto (entre otras cosas) mediante [`numpy.set_printoptions`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions)/[`numpy.printoptions()`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html), pero debes hacerlo solo temporalmente en un contexto controlado, no es buena idea imprimir los array completos por norma general:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
import numpy as np

rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('sound.wav')
with np.printoptions(threshold=np.inf):
    with open('440Hz.txt','w') as file:
        file.write(str(data))
```

En este caso, esto guardará en el archivo la misma cadena que verías al hacer `print(data)`, con el mismo formato (de hecho puedes hacer también `print(data, file=file)` en vez de `file.write(str(data))`):

> ```
> [    0   992  1923  2733  3372  3800  3991  3932  3627  3095  2369  1495
>    528  -471 -1442 -2323 -3058 -3602 -3921 -3994 -3818 -3402 -2774 -1972]
> ```

Otra opción más apropiada generalmente para arrays de una o dos dimensiones es que uses [`numpy.savetxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
import numpy as np

rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('sound.wav')
np.savetxt("440Hz.txt", data, fmt='%i')
```

Lo que para tu caso generara un archivo con cada entero del array en una línea:

> -19701
>   -31047
>   18948
>   ...

Eventualmente se puede usar también [`numpy.ndarray.tofile()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html), aunque está pensada principalmente para almacenar arrays en modo binario, no como texto:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
import numpy as np

rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('sound.wav')
data.tofile("440Hz.txt", sep=" ", format="%s")
```

En este caso el archivo contendrá una única línea (muy larga...) con todos los enteros separados por un espacio:

> -19701 -31047 18948 ...

---

Como nota aparte, no se si es un error tipográfico, pero con `file.close` no cierras el archivo, `close` es un método y debes llamarlo: `file.close()`.